# Fourier transform gives wrong result

Tags: fourier-analysis

The expression

```
I InverseFourierTransform[FourierTransform[1/t, t, w]/w, w, x]//FullSimplify
```

gives

```
EulerGamma + Log[Abs[x]]
```

while the correct result should be

```
EulerGamma - I Pi + Log[x]
```

the same as of the following:

```
f[n_, s_] := ((-1)^n n!)/s^(n + 1)
Limit[1/2 f[-1 + h, s] + 1/2 f[-1 - h, s], h -> 0]
```

Comment: I am not an expert on this, but looking at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522986/what-is-the-fourier-transform-of-1-x), it seems to me that the additive constant is irrelevant in any setting where the Fourier transform exists at all.

Comment: Also as antiderivatives, `Log[x]` and `Log[Abs[x]]` differ by piecewise constants on the real line.

Answer (score 1):

By using the additional `Assumptions ->` in the script leads to

```
I*InverseFourierTransform[FourierTransform[1/t, t, w]/w, w, x, Assumptions -> x>=0]//FullSimplify
```

giving the result

```
EulerGamma + Log[x] + I*Pi*(1 - Sign[x])/2
```

The last portion of the result can, essentially, be ignored.

Comment: It is essentially the same result as in the question, which is wrong